# How to regenrate java classes from xjc ant while xsd's are up to date

Tags: ant, xsd, jaxb, xjc

If `xsd` are up to date , then `xjc` are not generating the class.

I want classes always to be generated..

```
<target name="jaxbSource" description="Generate jaxb objects">

            <echo message="Generate jaxb objects for CategoryAPIRequest..." />
                <xjc source="2.0" schema="${basedir}/schemas/categoryAPI/CategoryAPIRequest.xsd" package="com.myrio.tm.company.categories.util.request"
                     destdir="${basedir}/src" binding="${basedir}/schemas/categoryAPI/binding.xml">
                    <produces dir="${basedir}/src" includes="**/*.java" />
                    <arg value="-extension" />
                </xjc> 

            <echo message="Generate jaxb objects for CategoryAPIReturn..." />
                <xjc source="2.0" schema="${basedir}/schemas/categoryAPI/CategoryAPIReturn.xsd" package="com.myrio.tm.company.categories.util.response"
                    destdir="${basedir}/src" binding="${basedir}/schemas/categoryAPI/binding.xml">
                    <produces dir="${basedir}/src" includes="**/*.java" />
                    <arg value="-extension" /> 
                </xjc> 

        </target>
```

-- My Binding xml is  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: What does that mean, if xsd are up to date?

Comment: First Time xsd will generate the java class .If second time xsd compile ,while there is no changed in xsd then xsd will show 'up to date' message come.

Comment: Why is it a problem that your code is up to date? You could have ant delete the generated code before `xjc` is run. Or depending on the plugin you use, you could use the `force="true"` attribute on `<produces>`.